# Text inline after h3

Tags: css

How can i get text to appear inline after a H3 tag?

```
<div>

    <H3>asdfsadfasd</H3> <p>afadsfadsf</p>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vbr39bm2/)

Comment: by applying some css to your code.

Comment: h3, p { float: left; }

Comment: why not wrap the text in a span and put it in the H3 tag? `<h3>Headline <span>inline text</span></h3>`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default, both `h3` and `p` are "block elements". That means they make space above and below to ensure they are the only thing on a given line (technically, they "fill their parent element" horizontally). Using CSS, this behavior can be overridden by applying the rule `display:inline` to both properties. See the example below.

You can read more about block-level elements on the Mozilla Developer's Network [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements).

```css
h3, p { display:inline }
```

```html
<div>
    <H3>asdfsadfasd</H3> <p>afadsfadsf</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I tried inline in the style attribute and it did not work. http://jsfiddle.net/vbr39bm2/3/ is there a difference in the two?

Comment: @asdfasdf you must apply it to both the `h3` and the `p`, you've applied it only to the `p`. http://jsfiddle.net/tzza5mod/

Answer (score 2):

Some options:

- Floating elements:

  ```
  h3, p {
      float: left;
  }
  div {
      overflow: hidden;
  }
  ```

  ```css
  h3, p {
    float: left;
  }
  div {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div>
    <h3>asdfsadfasd</h3>
    <p>afadsfadsf</p>
  </div>
  ```
- Floating + block:

  ```
  h3 {
      float: left;
  }
  div {
      overflow: hidden;
  }
  ```

  ```css
  h3 {
    float: left;
  }
  div {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div>
    <h3>asdfsadfasd</h3>
    <p>afadsfadsf</p>
  </div>
  ```
- Inline elements:

  ```
  h3, p {
      display: inline;
  }
  ```

  ```css
  h3, p {
    display: inline;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div>
    <h3>asdfsadfasd</h3>
    <p>afadsfadsf</p>
  </div>
  ```
- Inline-block elements:

  ```
  h3, p {
      display: inline-block;
  }
  ```

  ```css
  h3, p {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div>
    <h3>asdfsadfasd</h3>
    <p>afadsfadsf</p>
  </div>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question, just use `display: inline`.

```css
h3, p {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div>
    
    <H3>asdfsadfasd</H3> <p>afadsfadsf</p>
</div>
```

I'd recommend not doing it globally though. Instead apply a class that will make that pattern reusable for you across your site. Something more like this:

```css
.header__inline h3, .header__inline p {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__inline">
    <H3>asdfsadfasd</H3> <p>afadsfadsf</p>
</div>
```

And you might want to read up on (and play with) the `display` attribute: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/